# Como incorporar uma DLL a um projeto winForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso incorporar uma referência a um projeto winforms.

Eu cliquei em References, selecionei a referência e cliquei em propriedades, aí alterei a propriedade Embed Interop Types para true.

Ao compilar a solution dá o seguinte erro:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1759  Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'Berechit.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is missing either the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute. AppTeste    C:\project\AppTeste\CSC 1   Active

Comment: Essa DLL, foi desenvolvida por você? Ou é de terceiros?

Comment: esta DLL é um outro projeto que eu estou fazendo, mas gostaria de incorporar várias DLL, entre elas DLL desenvolvidas por mim e de terceiros. O objetivo principal é que o produto final não tenha as DLL utilizadas aparentes para o usuário final.

Comment: Qual a intenção de marcar `EmbedInteropTypes` como `true`?

Comment: Na verdade eu pensei que o EmbedInteropTypes como true era a forma de incorporar a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Para incoperar uma dll tens e ir á janela references e clicar o com botão direito depois clicas em add reference depois vais browser cicas no botão browse e selecionas a dll que queres dpois disso confirma que tá com um sinal de selecionado e clicas ok